# Where does "Additivity" show up besides measure theory?

Tags: abstract-algebra, lattice-orders

The properties of "additivity" or "$\sigma$-additivity" seem to be quite localized phenomenons at first glance, specific to measures or appropiate generalizations of those.

Let $L$ be a lattice. Elements $x,y\in L$ are *disjoint*, if $x\wedge y = \bot$ (smallest element). A map $f : L \to M$ into some commutative monoid $M$ is *additive*, if $f(x \vee y) = x + y$ whenever $x,y$ are disjoint. Something similar can be done with $\sigma$-additivity, where $M$ is a complete monoid.

I feel like there should be some interesting examples, where $L$ is not just a set of sets ordered by $\subseteq$. So:

> Where does "Additivity" show up besides measure theory?

(A more basic problem is perhaps finding instances, where disjointness is useful. Here are two examples: $x,y\in \mathbb Z_{\geq 0}$ are disjoint w.r.t. to $\mid$, if they are coprime; subgroups $M,N\subseteq G$ are disjoint, if $M\cap N \cong 1$. In totally ordered sets, disjointness is of course quite boring).

Comment: Perhaps it is of interest to note that any lattice $L$ can be represented as a lattice of sets ordered by $\subseteq$, namely the lattice of downsets of $L$ with a unique maximal element.

Comment: @MeesdeVries Perhaps. But it doesn't mean that one normally works with this representation. Well... I don't yet know what to expect as possible answers.

Comment: I seem to recall having seen the word "additivity" used in a different context: A mapping from one vector space to another is _linear_ iff it is both "additive" and "homogeneous". But perhaps that is not the same thing.

Comment: @MichaelHardy Probably not. The key assumption is disjointness.

Comment: What do you consider to be "measure theory"? Do "signed measures" fit within that? Or "measures" that are finitely additive but not countably additive?

Comment: @MichaelHardy well.... I guess finitely additive, but not $\sigma$-additive, is still okay. I want to get away from examples you can find in "any" book on measure theory.

Comment: More or less related, I'll add this example, from the book *General Lattice Theory* of George Grätzer, §IV.2. If $h$ denotes the *height function* and $\mathbf{L}$ is a lattice of finite length, then (Corollary 3) $\mathbf{L}$ is modular iff $h(a) + h(b) = h(a \vee b) + h(a \wedge b)$. Now, if $a$ and $b$ are disjoint, $h(a \wedge b) = h(0) = 0$, yielding $h(a \vee b) = h(a) + h(b)$. But of course it is only another example of this phenomenon...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example which is certainly not from measure theory:

Consider the lattice structure on the positive integers given by divisibility.  That is, $x \leq y$ if $x | y$.  Here the meets and joins are given by lcms and gcds, respectively, so "disjoint" means "relatively prime."  Then an additive (resp. multiplicative) function in the sense of number theory is precisely an additive function on this lattice with codomain the integers under addition (resp. multiplication).

Answer (score 4):

At some emotional level, the proof on page 17 of [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0203249.pdf)$^{\,\large\dagger}$ is my favorite part of it with Section 4.2 on pages 17 through 22 following closely. This is about additivity-without addition on structures that are no lattices but have some things in common with them. The purpose is to explain why additivity of probabilities should apply when the probabilities are purely epistemic, so that one has no relative frequencies or proportions of populations, etc.

Whether this is "measure theory" may be something one could argue about.

$\dagger$ My paper "Scaled Boolean Algebras", *Advances in Applied Mathematics*, 2002. (A pdf file.)

Comment: It is probably a good idea to explain what's in the link, for without it your answer in not quite understandable and it may stop working.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez : The part beginning with "This is about" and ending with "etc." says something about what it is.